# Insert line from file 2 into file 1 after certain letter/symbol

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, csh

I'm trying to combine two files at certain locations using `awk`/`sed`/`forloop`/`foreach`... whichever is the most simple.

First, I have file 1 which has ...

```
#   
#   
>  
#    
#     
>
```

etc..

And in my second file, I have just numbers (as many numbers as >'s in the other file).

```
Num1  
Num2   
Num3
```

etc...

I want to insert the numbers in order in file 2, after each > in the first file, such as...

```
#   
#   
> Num1  
#    
#     
> Num2
```

Thanks!

Comment: `using awk/sed` , so try something with those tools and  add it to the question.. see [how much research effort is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)... if you're a beginner, check the info pages for [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info) and [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info) to get started...

Comment: I had tried a few things prior, but was unable to figure it out. Next time I'll add in what I tried! It was my first time posting on here because I was unable to find similar answers when searching. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short **`awk`** solution:

```
awk '/^>/{ r=$0; if ((getline < "file2") > 0) $0=r OFS $0 }1' file1
```

Sample output:

```
#
#
> Num1
#
#
> Num2
```

Comment: Very compact and quite similar to Sundeep solution (added to my answer) +1!

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider `file1` and `file2` that we need to merge with your criteria:

```
$ more file1 file2
::::::::::::::
file1
::::::::::::::
#
#
>
#
#
>
#
#
>
::::::::::::::
file2
::::::::::::::
98
58
348
```

Then you can use the following `awk` command:

```
$ awk '/^#/{print $0; next}/^>/{printf "> "; getline < "file2" ; print $0}' file1
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
#
#
> 98
#
#
> 58
#
#
> 348
```

**Explanations:**

- `/^#/{print $0; next}` for lines that start with `#` just print it and go to the next line
- `/^>/{printf ">"; getline < "file2" ; print $0}` when a line starts with `>` you print `>` followed by the number that is extracted by the `getline` statement from `file2`.

Last but not least, just redirect the output of the command to a file in order to save the result via redirection operator `>`:

```
$ awk '/^#/{print $0; next}/^>/{printf "> "; getline < "file2" ; print $0}' file1 > result
```

Following Sundeep advice, you can even use a more compact command:

```
awk '/^>/ && (getline num < "file2")==1{$0 = $0 OFS num} 1'
```

where for lines that start with `>` you call the `getline` statement to fetch the next line from `file2` and store the content into `num` variable (`getline` will return `1` if it succeeds), this will then trigger the scoper `{$0 = $0 OFS num}` in which you replace the line content by itself followed by the `output field separator` (space by default) to which you concatenate the value stored in `num` variable. Last but not least, the `1` at the end of the `awk` command is used to trigger the default printing of the whole modified line contained in `$0`.

Comment: no probs, no idea why you are using `sed` when you have `awk`.. personally, I'd just use `getline`

Comment: @Sundeep: Actually you are right, even if the `sed` solution works it is too complex, a `getline < $FILE` is way more direct! I have edited my answer thanks

Comment: [getline has many caveats though](https://web.archive.org/web/20170524214527/http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline)... `awk '/^>/ && (getline num < "file2")>0{$0 = $0 OFS num} 1'`

Comment: @Sundeep: I have added your solution in the post as well! ;-) very compact I like it, I have changed the `>0` by `==1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r "/^>/R file2" file1 | sed -r "/>/d;s/^([^#])(.*)/> \1\2/"
```

The sed command `R file2` reads a line, always when triggered, from file2. But it produces some intermediate output, which needs to be adjusted (done by the sed behind the pipe) - here is the intermediate result before:

```
#   
#   
>  
Num1
#    
#     
>
Num2
```

The second sed invocation is just standand sed vodoo:

```
sed -r "/>/d;s/^([^#])(.*)/> \1\2/"
```

Delete the lines which are just ">" and replace the lines, not starting with a # with "> " in front. (\1=N, \2=umX)

```
#   
#   
> Num1
#    
#     
> Num2
```

Here is an alternative way, nearly identical:

```
sed -r "/^>/R file2" file1 | sed -r "/>/d;/^[^#]/s/(.*)/> \1/"
```

The second sed command, part 2 only matches lines which don't start with (and only consist of) #, replaces them with "> " in front.

A third approach would be, to replace file 2 with a modified version, which already contains the "> " in front of each line.

Answer (score 0):

No getline required:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0; next} {print $0 (/>/ ? " " a[++c] :"")}' file2 file1
```